# Shower hot water problem

Tags: plumbing

Why does my shower hot water flow slow down during showers? I find that I need to keep adding more hot water to keep a consistent temperature.

Comment: It depends on how fast your emptying the tank (i.e. shower head flow rate), how fast the tank can heat water (i.e. how much gas it burns), and how much water enters the tank (usually the same as the amount leaving) - you should be able to measure the shower flow rate by timing how long to fill a bucket, and how much gas is burned by looking at the gas meter when there isn't any hot water

Answer (score 2):

How big is your hot water tank, and how high is the thermostat set? It sounds like you're running out of hot water, so you have to keep turning up the valve so the (now cooler) hot water can compensate

Comment: Maybe, but has new 40 gal gas A O Smith ProMax set at the highest setting. Had to do that to properly clean dishes in newer Bosch dishwasher. Believe me, the water is HOT and there should be plenty of it.

Comment: @user31892, it looks like you've created multiple accounts. Please consider registering and merging your accounts, which will allow you to comment on and edit your own posts. See the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page for more information.